# Flutter firestore: Image not displaying

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my code using the chrome, I tried to call on image from the database but it's not displaying. Other info display perfectly well.

This is my code:

```
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? selectedUser;
QueryDocumentSnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>? numberUser;
final users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('USERS').snapshots();

StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>>(
                  stream: users,
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return ListView.builder(
                          itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
                          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                            return Card(
                              child: ListTile(
                                onTap: () {
                                  setState(() {
                                    selectedUser = snapshot.data!.docs[index];
                                  });
                                },
                                title: Text(snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                                        .get("First name") +
                                    " " +
                                    snapshot.data!.docs[index]
                                        .get("Last name")),
                              ),
                            );
                          });
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return const Text('Error');
                    } else {
                      return const Center(child: Text('No user yet'));
                    }
                  }),
                 Container(
              width: screenWidth * 0.4,
              color: Colors.grey.shade500,
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      height: screenHeight * 0.6,
                      width: screenWidth * 0.3,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                            image: NetworkImage(
                              selectedUser?['Profile picture'] ?? '',
                            ),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover),
                      ),
                    ),
                    //Other information display well
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

This same code worked with a previous project I worked on sometime ago. But don't know why this time it's not working. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

Couple recommendations.

If you want to use the way you currently have with using Firebase Database, you're selectedUser?['Profile picture'] might not be a valid url to display the images. You use Uri.parse({url}).isAbsolute to validate it works before trying to display it. Something like this:

```dart
bool _isUrlValid(String? url){
if (url == null) return false;
return Uri.parse(url).isAbsolute;
}
```

With this, the function will return false if there is no url or that it doesn't match the proper construction of a url.

I would recommend storing any images that a user can upload, profile picture for example, into Firebase's Cloud Storage. Then you can get the download url for that profile picture from the Cloud Storage and put it in your database.
Here is Firebase's official documentation on how to use it: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage

An example of adding a profile picture function that can be within repository:

```dart
// XFile comes from the image_picker or camera package, you can use this or
// whichever class you use for your images
@override
  Future<void> addProfilePic(XFile profilePic) async {
FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.instance;
    final String downloadImageUrl;
    const String profileFilePath = 'users/{path-to-current-user}';
    try {
      final referenceProfilePic = storage
          .ref(profileFilePath)
          .child('Profile Picture');

        final imageTask = referenceProfilePic.putFile(File(profilePic.path));

        final snapshot = await imageTask;

// You can get the url for the image with the following code, that way you
// can still put it in Firestore Database and use that url for your 
// selectedUser?['Profile picture']
        downloadImageUrl = await snapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();

// Here you can add a method to put the downloadImageUrl into the database

    } catch (e) {
// Be sure to add error handling, this is a placeholder
      log(
        'Uploading profile picture didn\'t work - ${e.toString()}',
      );
      throw (_) {
        e.toString();
      };
    }
  }
```

All and all, use the Cloud Storage for images and get the url when you do upload them. This should fix your error and be easier to handle when uploading the images. It's designed to store anything bigger than text data, like audio, videos, and of course images. You can use the isValidUrl() method for this as well, and just have a default profile image if the user doesn't want a profile picture.